# redefinition , different basic types for string

Tags: c++

loadFromTextFile.h

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

class loadFromTextFile{
private:
    int rows = 0;
    int columns = 0;
    std::string file_path;
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > nodeGrid;
    void process(std::string);
public:
    loadFromTextFile(std::string);
    loadFromTextFile();

};
```

loadFromTextFile.cpp

```
#include "loadFromTextFile.h"

using namespace std;

//implementions
loadFromTextFile::loadFromTextFile(string filePath){
    file_path = filePath;
    string line;
    ifstream f(file_path);

    if (!f.is_open())
        perror("error while opening file");
    while (getline(f, line)) {
        process(line);
    }
    if (f.bad())
        perror("error while reading file");

    cout << "total rows" << rows;
}
void loadFromTextFile::process(string s){
    rows++;
    cout << s<<endl;

}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "loadFromTextFile.h"

int main(){

    std::string path = "E:\\10x10.txt"; 
    loadFromTextFile(path);
    //loadFromTextFile("E:\\10x10.txt");//works

}
```

anyone knows why am i getting a "path" redefinition ; different basic types for the string path, however when i pass the string directly instead of using the variable path it works.

Comment: Does this give errors when you rename `path` to something like `test_path_h`?

Comment: yes it does, however if i enter the path in like this : loadFromTextFile("E:\\10x10.txt"); it works fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`loadFromTextFile(path);` is equivalent to `loadFromTextFile path;`, a declaration.

`loadFromTextFile("E:\\10x10.txt");` can't be interpreted as a declaration, so instead it's treated as a conversion expression, creating and destroying a temporary object. It compiles, but probably isn't what you want either.

You probably want to declare a named variable, so the data it loads is still available afterwards:

```
loadFromTextFile loaded(path);
```

Comment: And if he really doesn't want a named variable, and just wants to use the constructor and destructor for their side effects, he can do `(void)loadFromTextFile(path);`